# do not build android app on ionic cordova (error message showing)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm new developer. There is error found to create build android APK.

already set into the environment variable but nothing happen.. Please help me. Give me the solution of this.

D:\Ionic\testPushNotification>cordova build android
Running command: D:\Ionic\Node\node.exe D:\Ionic\testPushNotification\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\Ionic\testPushNotification
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=D:\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
BUILD FAILED

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the site guidelines on asking questions in [help]. You should include all code and error messages a *text* in your question, not as pictures. Pictures are often difficult to read and the textual content cannot be copied/pasted.

Answer (score 5):

As the error suggests the problem is with your Android path,
First include the android sdk path, if you already have done it, the path is wrong!

Check your ANDROID_HOME: **export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk**
It should point to the Android SDK Folder: **export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools**